# How to link between url "domain.com/abc" to "domain.com/cde" using relative url?

Tags: html, url, href

How do I go from `http://run.plnkr.co/jfGlh6QrAx48S4lZ/#!/main` to `http://run.plnkr.co/jfGlh6QrAx48S4lZ/#!/services` using  tag?

I tried through the following:
`<a href="#/services">` but its not working it is going to `http://run.plnkr.co/jfGlh6QrAx48S4lZ/#!/main#%2Fservices`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
<a href="#!/services">
```

The link that starts with the hash (`#`) will keep the same URL you currently view and only change the hash part (the `#` and everything after it).

Comment: Sorry I have less than 15 reputation. Even if I mark it is not recorded.

Comment: Vote and Mark as correct are two different things :)

Comment: I know but my vote is not being counted now because of the reputation criteria so I did what I could do. Thank you.